# WPF Tab_SelectionChanged Event

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to lock my wpf tab to change the index but I'm getting dispatcher error messages with my code below. Where am I doing wrong? I'm aware that once the content changes, it fires the same event but is there any other event to fire for this ?

```
    private void MainTabControl_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(e.Source is TabControl))
            return;
        if (Helper.GetProperty<bool>("IsTabLocked")) // my condition
        {
            MessageBox.Show("tab is locked");
            e.Handled = true;
            return;
        }
```

Comment: Is this helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/418006/how-can-i-disable-a-tab-inside-a-tabcontrol

Comment: not really, but e.cancel = true, I think I need something like this. SelectionChangedEventArgs have any attribute like this ?

Comment: Yes, Handled Property. But not sure whether it would work in "SelectionCHANGED" event. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.routedeventargs.handled.aspx

Comment: it does not work as in my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could come up with a custom solution with the source code below, but I'm sure someone has thought about this and there is an event or an easier trick which I've never heard before.

```
    static int TabControlIndex = 0;
    private void MainTabControl_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(e.Source is TabControl))
            return;
        if (TabControlIndex == MainTabControl.SelectedIndex)
            return;
        if (Helper.GetProperty<bool>("IsTabLocked") && TabControlIndex != MainTabControl.SelectedIndex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("locked");
            MainTabControl.SelectedIndex = TabControlIndex;
            // = true;
            return;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution that I can see is setting the required tab as the selected one when the execution comes to SelectionChanged event.

Try something like below.

```
int MyPreferedTabPageIndex = 1; // ?

private void MainTabControl_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Helper.GetProperty<bool>("IsTabLocked")) // my condition
        {
            MainTabControl.SelectedIndex = MyPreferedTabPageIndex ;
            MessageBox.Show("tab is locked");

        }
    }
```

Comment: the problem here is that it fires the same event more than 1 time for each change. I've added a control to prevent t other changes in selection content. How are you going to update the index ?

Comment: and i guess there becomes an infinitive loop since once you change the index, it fires the event again and again and again, which was my exact problem. e.Handled = true; didn't work.