# Is there a way to disable a TabPage inside a TabControl?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tabcontrol

I don't really need to disable them because I either disable the `TabControl` or enable it. But when the `TabControl` is disabled, I want the tab pages look disabled (greyed out).

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/418006/how-can-i-disable-a-tab-inside-a-tabcontrol. The best answer to that question is http://stackoverflow.com/a/418033/635634

Comment: Yes sorry forgot to mention that.

Comment: But it says the header will still be enabled. I assumed it will look enabled still which is what I am trying to solve.

Comment: @JoanVenge - The standard winforms tab control doesn't provide that much flexibility.

Comment: If you do it from the Controls level yes use a something like this foreach (Control control in ctls) {
        control.Enabled = enable;  then you may need to call the method recursively if there are multiple controls

Comment: Check my example. It combines all 3 methods mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/418006/how-can-i-disable-a-tab-inside-a-tabcontrol/418033 to do what you need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What people have mentioned below won't do the trick individually, but combined they will. Try this out:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //Disable tabPage2
        this.tabPage2.Enabled = false; // no casting required.
        this.tabControl1.Selecting += new TabControlCancelEventHandler(tabControl1_Selecting);
        this.tabControl1.DrawMode = TabDrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
        this.tabControl1.DrawItem += new DrawItemEventHandler(DisableTab_DrawItem);
    }
    private void DisableTab_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        TabControl tabControl = sender as TabControl;
        TabPage page = tabControl.TabPages[e.Index];
        if (!page.Enabled)
        {
            //Draws disabled tab
            using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(SystemColors.GrayText))
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawString(page.Text, page.Font, brush, e.Bounds.X + 3, e.Bounds.Y + 3);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Draws normal tab
            using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(page.ForeColor))
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawString(page.Text, page.Font, brush, e.Bounds.X + 3, e.Bounds.Y + 3);
            }
        }
    }

    private void tabControl1_Selecting(object sender, TabControlCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        //Cancels click on disabled tab.
        if (!e.TabPage.Enabled)
            e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I just tried but I don't see the Enabled property in tabpage controls. How did you get yours?

Comment: You can cast it as well. ((Control)tabPage2).Enabled = false; 

I've tested both ways and they work.

Comment: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/18919663/vs%20samples/disable%20tab%20test.zip

Here is my project I tested this in.

Comment: Ok I just tried it but it doesn't disable the tab header itself. The controls inside the tab are disabled but the tab pages look as if they are enabled.

Comment: Did you try my sample? Mine disables the header tab as well. 

That's what does:
this.tabControl1.DrawMode = TabDrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
            this.tabControl1.DrawItem += new DrawItemEventHandler(DisableTab_DrawItem);

Comment: Thanks for the sample file. Your tabs do look disabled, in the app (Photoshop) I am launcging this app, the tabs look old-win32 style, i.e. solid gray color not the win7 style. So I guess this is a different issue.

Comment: Try adjusting the: new SolidBrush(SystemColors.GrayText) and try different colors

Comment: Thanks, same result, it didn't make a different when I set it to red.

Comment: I noticed your tab pages use UseVisualBackStyle to True, will try that.

Comment: Could you give me a sample? Maybe I can try a couple things.

Comment: You also need to make sure you add:
Application.EnableVisualStyles();

to your Program.cs page.

Comment: If not, can I at least get a best answer? :P

Comment: Thanks, I would but I think photoshop is doing weird stuff to apps that are children of it, so it wouldn't make a difference I think. I have EnableVisualStyles in Program.cs though.

Answer (score 3):

Try using This code it works:

```
private void tabControl1_Selecting(object sender, TabControlCancelEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.TabPage == tabControl1.TabPages[1])
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }            
        }
```

Keep the index or name of the tabpage you want to disable in the if condition here i have kept index as 1.
:)

Answer (score 2):

Rewrote solution provided by @Corylulu to incapsulate everything in a control itself.

```
public class DimmableTabControl : TabControl
{
    public DimmableTabControl()
    {
        DrawMode = TabDrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
        DrawItem += DimmableTabControl_DrawItem;
        Selecting += DimmableTabControl_Selecting;
    }

    private void DimmableTabControl_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        TabPage page = TabPages[e.Index];
        using(SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(page.Enabled ? page.ForeColor : SystemColors.GrayText))
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawString(page.Text, page.Font, brush, e.Bounds.X + 3, e.Bounds.Y + 3);
        }
    }

    private void DimmableTabControl_Selecting(object sender, TabControlCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if(!e.TabPage.Enabled)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
}
```