# VB.net disable a TabPage of a TabControl

Tags: vb.net, winforms, tabcontrol, tabpage

I currently have a form that uses `TabControl` which has 5 `TabPages`. I want to create a button that could disable a specific `TabPage`.

I have tried

```
TabPage1.Enabled = False
```

But it does not work. How do I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I disable a tab inside a TabControl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/418006/how-can-i-disable-a-tab-inside-a-tabcontrol)

Comment: can you try this one   Me.TabControl1.TabPages(1).Enabled = False

Comment: After you disable it, perhaps make it invisible? `Visible = False`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you need to use the TabPages collection. Add a button to your form and try this

```
Private Sub Button1_Click( sender As Object,  e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        TabControl1.TabPages(0).Enabled =false
End Sub
```

It's a base zero array, so in your case it should be from 0-4.

Or you can access it from the text of the tab

```
Private Sub Button2_Click( sender As Object,  e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim tabPage As TabPage

    For Each tabPage In TabControl1.TabPages
        If tabPage.Text ="TabPage2"
            tabPage.Enabled =False
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: That does a bit different thing - it disables a *content* of the `TabPage`, not the `TabPage` itself. The page remains enabled. Nice to know anyway, might get useful.

Answer (score 4):

Currently, the following two code blocks does the same thing: disables all the controls on that TabPage (Sets Control.Enabled = False). The tab itself is still visible and selectable from the TabControl, it is not hidden. The tab is selectable and all the elements appear disabled.

```
TabMyTab.Enabled = False
```

`MyTabControl.TabPages(4).Enabled = False` where the TabPages(4) is the 5th in the TabControl collection.

Your initial code should work if that is your intent.

If you want to disable the tab similar to i.e. `button.Enabled = False` which does not allow the control to be used, you will need to do something different as disabling a TabPage as in the code above disables all controls in that tab. If this is what you want, keep reading. A lot of programmers suggest using the TabControl to disallow the tab from being selected by selecting a different or the previously selected tab. This is the most effective way I know. I would implement this as follows:

```
Private PreviousTab As New TabPage
Private CurrentTab As New TabPage

Private Sub TabControlName_Deselected(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.TabControlEventArgs) Handles TabControlName.Deselected
        PreviousTab = e.TabPage
End Sub

Private Sub TabControlName_Selected(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.TabControlEventArgs) Handles TabControlName.Selected
        CurrentTab = e.TabPage
        If (PreviousTab.Name <> CurrentTab.Name) And (CurrentTab.Name = UnselectableTab.Name) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Tab disabled.", "Selection Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
            TabControlName.SelectedTab = PreviousTab
        End If
End Sub
```

Substitute your own values for "UnselectableTab" and "TabControlName" for your project.

Comment: I think there're a couple of issues here, not the least being the ambiguity of "Enabled" and the fact that the property is marked "This member is not meaningful for this control"! I generally use this to disable all the controls on the tab, for example, if a license has expired. And it works either directly - `myTab.Enabled = True|False` - or using the index as @j3osh6 says.

Answer (score 2):

You can combine the use of disabling the tab, that way the behavior is dynamic if you change which tabs are enabled or disabled in code.

```
Private Sub TabControl1_Deselected(sender As Object, e As TabControlEventArgs) Handles TabControl1.Deselected
    PreviousTab = e.TabPage
End Sub
```

.

```
Private Sub TabControl1_Selected(sender As Object, e As TabControlEventArgs) Handles TabControl1.Selected
    If Not e.TabPage.Enabled Then
        TabControl1.SelectedTab = PreviousTab
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disabled a tab by setting its `Enabled` property:

`TabControl1.TabPages("tbPage1").Enabled = False`