# disable tab choose in tabcontrol C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Form and a tabcontrol with 2 tabs and a timer in it. I want to know how to disable click tab2 when Form load and enable it when a timer tick for amount of time.

I have tried `tab2.Enabled = false;`, it works fine but people still click and choose that tab (contents are disabled).

Thank you!

Sorry about my english!

Ok the solution is:

```
 private void tabControl1_Selecting(object sender, TabControlCancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.TabPage == tabPage2)
        e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Comment: I assume "False" is a typo (in C#, it is "false"). IOW, "False" is false.

Comment: yes. my bad typing. thank you! :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/418006/how-can-i-disable-a-tab-inside-a-tabcontrol

Comment: Thank you Ali. :) It works now!

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you have an event handler for the tab's click event, you need to unhook it when the form initializes, something like this:

```
tab2.Click -= tab2_Click;
```

...and then hook it back up in the Timer's trip event something like this:

```
tab2.Click += tab2_Click;
```

Again, this assumes that you do have a tab2_Click(sender object, eventargs e) event handler defined already.

Comment: no i don't have it! but i it works now :) thank you for your idea!