# How to hide a page from tab control c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm programming a windows application program, using winforms c#
I have a tab control that contains so many pages I need to hide some of these tabs from non-admin users,
for example
if user is an admin no pages will be hided, else page number 1 and 2 will be hided and other pages will be shown,
I don't want to remove pages, just hide because in the program I made you can sign out without closing the program and sign in again as an admin

Comment: You also follow this, there has a solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/552579/how-to-hide-tabpage-from-tabcontrol

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/552579/how-to-hide-tabpage-from-tabcontrol) thread.

As [amazedsaint](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45956/amazedsaint) said:

> Visiblity property has not been implemented on the Tabpages, and there is no Insert method also.
>
> You need to manually insert and remove tab pages.
>
> Here is a work around for the same.
>
> http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/18344-Hiding-Showing-Tabpages-Tabcontrol.aspx

Answer (score 0):

No way to hide it ,you will have to remove pages an re add them for admin user

```
tabControl.TabPages.Remove(tabPage);


tabControl.TabPages.Add(tabPage);
```

Answer (score 0):

As seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418006/how-can-i-disable-a-tab-inside-a-tabcontrol) you can however disable/enable tabs. While this won't make then invisible, you can restrict access. That should get you going in a workable direction.

I'd personally also put all the restricted tabs at the end, but that's just a point of personal taste.